# Strong force gets weaker at small distances yet approximated by -1/r potential

Tags: potential, approximations, strong-force

My particle physics textbook (by Martin and Shaw) has confused me, it states in ch.7 that the strong force gets weaker at small distances, and that it can be approximated by $V(r) = -\frac{4 \alpha_s}{3 r}$ for $r<0.1fm$, so doesn't this potential suggest the opposite? $Force = -\nabla V = \frac{4 \alpha_s}{3 r^2}$ so the force goes to infinity as r goes to zero. I know that the strong coupling constant $\alpha_s$ is not really constant, but according to the book it's approximately constant when $r<0.1fm$, so what's going on?

Comment: The corrections are logarithmic.

Comment: Do you mean that $\alpha_s$ goes to 0 logarithmically overpowering the inverse square? Or higher order diagram corrections or something?

Comment: No.  The Fourier Xform of the potential would be roughly $C/{{k}^{2}}\log (k/\mu )$ as $k\to \infty $, so the potential would go something like $-C/r\log (\mu r)$ as $r\to 0$ .

Answer (score -1):

I understand the strong force to be the result of a competition between the Coulomb electrostatic forces between charged particles, and the magnetic forces resulting from the high speed motion of these charges. Two charges moving parallel to each other develop a magnetic attraction force and the ratio between the two is given by(see this ref http://www.physnet.org/modules/pdf_modules/m124.pdf); fm/fe=(v/c)^2. Thus when v is very near to c, the two forces are in balance and you have asymptotic freedom like situation. But far away the electrostatic force is the dominant one. The force can change from attraction to repulsion by changes of the sing of the charges or the direction of motion. 
Due to such balancing, the forces are negligible inside and outside and are effective only around the size/radius of a particle.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an electromagnetic effect, can you cite this?

Comment: I'm almost certain this is wrong. The strong force has a completely different set of symmetries than the electromagnetic force; electromagnetism has U(1) as a gauge group, and the strong force has SU(3).

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. The strong force is a separate thing from electromagnetism. The strong force is mediated by gluons, electromagnetism is mediated by photons.

Comment: The different names given for forces are for convenience and don't necessarily reflect a change in origin of the force. See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force     Containing so many names all derived from the Coulomb and Ampere forces.  In general and due to the presence of many participants, the potential may be described by a mix of; constants + various powers of r + various powers of 1/r .